# Removing a node from a linked list in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linked-list

I'm trying to learn C++ and there is a small confusion I have.

The text which I am learning from tells me that if I want to delete a node of type `const T&` I should first create a new pointer of that node type, then delete it using the inbuilt C++ `delete[]`. However, what happens if I just set the link from the to-be-deleted node's previous element to the to-be-deleted node's next element? Something like:

```
*p = node.previous;
p-> next = node.next;
```

Or will this cause a memory leak?

I'm confused because I read somewhere else to never, ever delete pointers willy-nilly, but the example code I am working with has something along the lines of:

```
Node<T> *p = node-to-be-deleted;
delete p;
```

What is the best way to delete the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your node looks like this:

```
struct Node
{
    Node*  previous;
    Node*  next;

    SomeType data;
};
```

Then:

```
*p = node.previous;
p-> next = node.next;
```

Then **YES**. This will cause a memory leak.
It also leaves `p->next->prev` pointing at the wrong node.

> I'm confused because I read somewhere else to never, ever delete pointers willy-nilly, but the example code I am working with has something along the lines of:

Yes the best way is to "never delete pointers". But this has to go along with some context. You should not be deleting pointers manually because pointers should be managed by an objects that control their lifespan. The simplest of these objects are smart pointers or containers. But for this situation that would be overkill (as you are creating the container).

As you are creating the container (a list) you will need to do the management yourself (Note C++ already has a couple of lost types std::list for a list of values of type t or boost::ptr_list for a list of pointers to T). But it is a good exercise to try and do it yourself.

Here is an example on code review of a beginner making a list and the comments it generated:

http://codereview.stackexchange.com: [Linked list in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13060/507)

I hope this helps in explains on how to create and delete objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
Node* p = new Node; // This is how you allocate a node
delete p; // This is how you delete it
```

The delete[] operator should be used on dynamically allocated **arrays**:

```
Node* nodelist = new Node[ 4 ]; // nodelist is now a (dynamically allocated) array with 4 items.
delete[] nodelist; // Will delete all 4 elements (which is actually just one chunk of memory)
```

Comment: So would my first implementation where I just dereference its pointers cause a memleak?

Comment: Yes, although you probably meant `p`, not `*p`. This is the first response to googling *linked list example c++*: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html just go ahead and dig into this language, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
void deleteNode( Node * p )
{
    Node * temp = p->next;
    p->data = p->next->data;
    p->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

Heres something i did a few months ago.

```
template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::remove(int pos)
{
    if (pos < 1 || pos > size)
    {
        throw pos;
    }
    ListNode * temp;
    if (pos == 1)
    {
        temp=head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    else
    {
        int i=1;
        ListNode * prev = head;

        while(i<pos-1)
        {
            i++;
            prev=prev->next;
        }
        temp = prev->next;

        prev->next = (prev->next)->next;

    }
    --size;
    return temp->item;
}
```

Comment: This is C++. Let's assume he's allocated with `new`, then **never ever** delete with `free`, but with `delete`.

Comment: @SchwitJanwityanujit because there is **no** guarantee that that `malloc()` and `new` allocate from the same pool. It will result in *undefined behaviour* to use malloc+delete or new+free.

Comment: You are freeing `node->next` when you should be freeing `node` instead. And you are not checking `next` for a NULL pointer before accessing its members, in case the last node in the list is the node being freed. And you are not taking `nde->previous` into account at all.

Comment: @gustafr: being C++, he should be using `std::list` instead of implementing a linked list manually.

Comment: Haha good point @RemyLebeau, but I guess OP wanted to learn the basics of memory management in C++, hence the example with a linked list. **Every** C++ programmer should create a few linked list implementations manually, as well as memory pools, thread pools and whatnot, before using the standard library containers. Just to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a `Node` directly only makes sense if `Node` implements a destructor to update the `previous` and `next` pointers of the surrounding `Node` instances, eg:

```
Node::~Node()
{
    if (previous) previous->next = next;
    if (next) next->previous = previous;
}

Node *p = node-to-be-deleted;
delete p;
```

Otherwise, you have to update the `Node` pointers before then deleting the `Node` in question, eg:

```
Node *p = node-to-be-deleted;
if (p->previous) p->previous->next = p->next;
if (p->next) p->next->previous = p->previous;
delete p;
```

With that said, the best approach is to no implement a linked list manually to begin with.  In C++, use a `std::list` container instead, and let it handle these details for you.